# Input format for logistic regression in scikit-learn as in R

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When Using logistic regression in `R`, the data input for the 'glm' function (family = binomial) can be: (?family) in several formats, and specifically in the format of:

> ......
>
> For the binomial and quasibinomial families the response can be
>   specified in one of three ways:
>
> ......
>
> As a numerical vector with values between 0 and 1, interpreted as the
>   proportion of successful cases (with the total number of cases given
>   by the weights)....

I have aggregated data that represents proportion of success out of trials (number between 0 and 1) and their equivalent weights, I'm interested in applying logistic regression with it, which would be trivial to use in R.

Unfortunately i cant use R in this project, and  would like to use `scikit-learn` to estimate the logistic regression coefficients . More precise, i'm looking to apply the `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression` in a form of input that will allow me to insert the model proportions and wights, in a similar fashion as  available in R.

example:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1,0], [1,1,1,0],[1,1,1,1],[2,2,1,1] , [2,2,1,1],[2,2,1,0] , [3,3,1,0] ],columns=['a', 'b','Trials','Success'])

logistic = linear_model.LogisticRegression()
#this works
logistic.fit(X=df[['a','b','Trials']] , y=df.Success)
logistic.predict_proba(df[['a','b','Trials']])
prob_to_success = logistic.predict_proba(df[['a','b','Trials']])[:,1]


    prob_to_success

Out[51]:  array([ 0.45535843,  0.45535843,  0.45535843,  0.42212169,  0.42212169,
        0.42212169,  0.38957565])

#How can i use the following Data?
df_agg = df.groupby(['a','b'] , as_index=False)['Trials','Success'].sum()
df_agg["Prop"] = df_agg.Success / (df_agg.Trials)
df_agg

 #I want to use Prop & Trials as weights in df_agg
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Convert to log-odds form and use linear regression on the transformation.  Sklearn doesn't seem to have a quasi-binomial conversion for logistic regression.  As you said, trivial in R but sklearn seems to not have anything of the sort.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use weights, you can use them in the fit function of `LogisticRegression`:

```
fit(X, y, sample_weight=None)
```

Comment: Notice that using that argument with Proportions throws the following error ValueError: Unknown label type: (array([ 0. , 0.66666667]),)